# Comparing two latest rows and return true or false based on location_id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table name Locations which is having the three fields. I need to find the latest two rows for a particular person id based on last_update_date and compare the location_id of these two latest rows and return true if both the location_id is same else return false.

I tried writing the query using join but doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Table Snippet.
Snippet1:

```
Locations       
person_id   last_update_date              location_id
368         21/10/08 14:37                     234
368         28-02-00 06:18:12.000000000 AM     431
368         11-02-98 03:56:33.000000000 AM     431
368         13-01-98 08:50:37.000000000 AM     212
```

Snippet2:

```
person_id   last_update_date              location_id
368         21/10/08 14:37                     null
368         28-02-00 06:18:12.000000000 AM     431
368         11-02-98 03:56:33.000000000 AM     431
368         13-01-98 08:50:37.000000000 AM     212
```

Snippet3:

```
person_id   last_update_date              location_id
368         21/10/08 14:37                     431
368         28-02-00 06:18:12.000000000 AM     431
368         11-02-98 03:56:33.000000000 AM     431
368         13-01-98 08:50:37.000000000 AM     212
```

Snippet4:

```
person_id   last_update_date              location_id
368         21/10/08 14:37                     431
```

For the above table snippet1 two latest rows for person id 368 is the first two rows which is not having the same location_id, so I would like to return false in this case. Please help me with the oracle query for the same.
Snippet2, query should return false.
Snippet3, query should return true.
Snippet4, query should return false as there is no other row with same person_id to compare with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option; `test` CTE is what you already have, useful code begins at line #7.

```
SQL> with locations (person_id, last_update_date, location_id) as
  2    (select 368, to_date('21.10.2008 14:37', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 234 from dual union all
  3     select 368, to_date('28.02.2000 06:18', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 431 from dual union all
  4     select 368, to_date('11.02.1998 03:56', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 431 from dual union all
  5     select 368, to_date('13.01.1998 08:50', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 212 from dual
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8    (select person_id, last_update_date, nvl(location_id, -1) location_id,
  9       row_number() over (partition by person_id order by last_update_date desc) rnd
 10     from locations
 11    )
 12  select person_id,
 13         min(last_update_date) min_date,
 14         max(last_update_date) max_date,
 15         case when min(location_id) <> max(location_id) or count(*) = 1 then 'false'
 16              else 'true'
 17         end flag
 18  from temp
 19  where rnd <= 2
 20  group by person_id;

 PERSON_ID MIN_DATE   MAX_DATE   FLAG
---------- ---------- ---------- -----
       368 28.02.2000 21.10.2008 false

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT: how to use a CTE]**

CTE (common table expression, or *with factoring clause*) has its syntax. You can't invent your own.

Not like you used it:

```
(SELECT person_id,
        last_update_date,
        location_id,
        ROW_NUMBER ()
           OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY last_update_date DESC)
           rnd
   FROM locations)
 as temp, select pid, ...
```

but

```
WITH temp
     AS (SELECT person_id,
                last_update_date,
                location_id,
                ROW_NUMBER ()
                OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY last_update_date DESC)
                   rnd
           FROM locations)
  SELECT pid, ...
```

Comment: Can you help me with the exact oracle query for the same. I am trying below query but seems to be some syntax error.                                                                                                 (select person_id, last_update_date, location_id,
           row_number() over (partition by person_id order by last_update_date desc) rnd from locations) as temp, select pid, min(last_update_date) min_date, max(last_update_date) max_date, case when min(location_id) <> max(location_id) then 'false' else 'true'  end flag from temp where rnd <= 2  group by pid;

Comment: This *is* exact Oracle query; I just shortened column names. I've edited my message so that it reflects names you posted in the question. Have a look.

Comment: Can you check my query in comment and see where I am going wrong with syntax, it seems I can't use "as temp" in this query.

Comment: You misused CTE syntax. I edited my message (again), showing what you have done wrong.

Comment: Thanks for correcting, for me scenario can be the latest row location_id can be null as well, in that case this query is returning true but I am expecting false in that case because null can't be equals to any value.

Comment: In that case, in `temp` CTE, you could use something like `nvl(location_id, -1) location_id` (instead of only `location_id`); `-1` is a value that shouldn't exist in list of locations. It is line #8 in my query (I modified it).

Comment: There is one more scenario, this query is returning true in case there exists only one row for a particular person_id, in that scenario, query should return false.

Comment: Add `or count(*) = 1` into `case` (line #15).